# Mapping multiple IP Addresses to one DNS record

Tags: dns, ip-address, load-balancer

We are wanting to run 2 separate servers, one legacy server and one new server.

All new users will be put onto the new server and current users will be left on the legacy server for now. We want to keep the domain name they are hitting the same for both situations. When we are ready we will turn the legacy server off and roll all users onto the one box.

The users come in on different website addresses like (for example only):

myWebsite.com.au/User1
myWebsite.com.au/User2

Is there a way we can setup rules on our dns record that says that requests for a certain address go to a certain ip address? It's similar to a load balancing setup but I can only currently find ways to randomly switch between servers not create rules for the switch.

Any advice?

Comment: You can't do that with DNS.

Comment: Hi Tyson, Thanks for the reply. Is there anything we can add in that could do it?

Comment: You could use a sub domain like new.example.com, but then you will need to figure a way to get the new users redirected.

Comment: Yeah i was wanting to accomplish this so no redirection was required

Comment: This Question has an "XY Problem". You really need a solution to dispatching requests to different servers based on the (non-host, path part of the) URL. You thought of doing this via DNS and accidentally asked for a solution to that dead-end instead of asking what you really needed. An HTTP load balancer such as HAProxy can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a reverse proxy server who will redirect the urls with the username to the correct server. More info about setting up a reverse proxy server with IIS URL Rewrite can be found here: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Comment: This is a pretty poor answer - instead of linking to a solution, *provide* a solution here, even if you're summarizing another source. You can still give credit, but if the other site goes down, the answer doesn't become stale.